# Creating a user-generated post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I did some research and couldn't find a suitable answer so I'm reaching out.....

Using Rails 3.1 and trying to create a post for a user. When I go to create a test post I get the error:

```
Missing template events/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en, :en],
  :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:coffee, :erb, :builder]}
```

Is this a template or should I adjust my routes?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log you provided here, you should be posting to Events controller's create method.

The following is copied from your repo:

```
def create
  @event = current_user.events.build(params[:event])
  if @event.save
    flash[:success] = "Event Shared"
    redirect_to root_path
  #else
  #  render 'pages/about'
  end


  #@event = Event.new         what I had before
  #@title = "Create An Event"
end
```

So if `@event.save` failed, there's no redirect and the render is commented out. So by default, rails 3.1 will try to find the view file in the following order: events/create, application/create (it matches your log)

With failing event.save, you would most likely `render "new"` so that it will use events/new.html.erb for the view file. (of course this is not a must, you could render anything you want or even redirect if you like)

(Hope that what I am viewing on the repo isn't a modified one :) )

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Sometimes the ones right in front of you are hardest to see.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would need:

```
def create
  @event = current_user.events.build(params[:event])
  if @event.save
    flash[:success] = "Event Shared"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :new
  end   
end
```

It will use error messages you already have in a view.